# how to show tool tip on lwc datatable cells

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have lwc datatable, I am able to add button on cells where needed.
Similarly I wanted to show info icon with tool tip,
Tool tip will show dynamic information based on table record data.

Any guidance will be helpful.

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation), It only supports to display the URL value as a tooltip on a URL type fields.

Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdi2HUAR/hover-tooltip-for-lightningdatatable-lightningdatatable).